# Did I do something wrong in calculating the market equilibrium?

Tags: supply-and-demand, markets

Sorry for asking such a silly question, but something seems odd about my answer to this question:

> Suppose that two consumers, Jeff and Walt, are the only consumers in the market for carrots.  Jeff’s demand curve is given by $Q_{Jeff}=10-2P$ and Walt’s demand curve is given by $Q_{Walt}=15-3P$.
>
> a) Find the market demand curve for carrots.
>
> b) Suppose the market supply curve is given by $Q_S = 2P$.  Find the market equilibrium price and quantity.

So, this is how I answered the question:

> (a)
>   Let $Q_{Jeff} = 10 – 2P$ and $Q_{Walt} = 15 – 3P$. Then, $Q_{Jeff} + Q_{Walt} = Q_D = (10 – 2P) + (15 – 3P) = 10 + 15 – 2P – 3P = 25 – 5P$. Therefore, the demand curve for carrots is $Q_D(P) = 25 – 5P$.
>
> (b)
>     Let $Q_S = 2P$ and $Q_D = 25 – 5P$. At the market equilibrium price:
>     $$2P = 25 – 5P
> \implies 2P + 5P = 25
> \implies 7P = 25
> \implies P = 25/7.$$
>   Thus, $P_E = 25/7$. Hence, $Q_E = 2P = 2(25/7) = 50/7$.

I guess I just wasn't expecting fractions in my answer. As far as I can tell, I did everything right. Did I screw up somewhere?

Comment: This looks quite fine. You did well!

Comment: Your solution is right. There could be always fractions for demand, supply quantities and for price.

Comment: Okay, thanks folks. I actually realised the odd feeling was a result of me using a proof-like method when my first-year economics class apparently calls for drawing the curves and adding them horizontally. I tried that method and got the same answer, so I suppose it must be probably right.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was not really a question, more of an affirmation request.

Comment: @denesp what happened to this vote?

Comment: @luchonacho Looks like it did not reach 5 votes need to close.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was not really a question, but a confirmation of results. This is never going to be of use to any other user.